# Can I use "due left" as meaning of "due west"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, phrases

According to the dictionary, "due" can be used to emphasize for "Straight, directly" i.g: "Go due west".

So,can I use "due left" as meaning of "due west"?

Comment: Only compass directions can be prefaced with 'due'.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHarvey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "due" in this sense is only used with compass directions (though it may be used as a joke with other directions, it is not standard)